# How to Design Joomla Style Plugin?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.7

First of All, I want to describe my Project Architecture so that it may help to answer my question.

```
My project uses jqGrid.
Controllers only define the Grid.
Then Models retrieve the Data for the Grid.
Models are used to Add/Edit/Delete Records.
Views are used to show the page.
```

Consider, I have 10 different kinds of Customers for my Project. My Project is a Hosted Solution which serves my all 10 Customers from a Single Source. Among them, 8 needs the exact same as I created. Only 2 are different than the common.

For say, imagine that, I want to show Product List. As my project is a hosted solution I can't change the Menu by which I can change the controller for the said 2 customers.

To solve the problem, I want to implement Plugin System like Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla plugins are triggered by various events that occur as the framework builds a page from a request. The documentation on the API order of execution and the various events that are triggered is pretty good and should give you some idea of what you need to do -

Events -- http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System

API Execution order - http://docs.joomla.org/API_Execution_Order